# Transform multi-row string to csv in Python

Tags: python

What is the best way to take this string:

```
1
2
3
4
a
b
c
d
1
2
3
4
a
b
c
d
1
2
3
4
a
b
c
d
```

and transform to a CSV containing 6 columns?

**Desired output**

Is a CSV which will be imported into Pandas:

```
1,a,1,a,1,a
2,b,2,b,2,b
```

etc..

Updated desired output as per comments to 6 rows.

Updated.  I can get the first row like this if I assign the string to `l` variable:

```
l.split()[0::4]

['1', 'a', '1', 'a', '1', 'a']
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I see 4 columns here, not 6.,

Comment: How are you deciding where to put each item?

Comment: Please see my update which shows how I get the first row and explains the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n") 
    for i in range(4):
        d = list()
        for j in range(i, len(data), 4):
            d.append(data[j])
        with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv:
            csv.write(','.join(d)+"\n")
```

Comment: you can do shorter: `d = data[i::4]`

Answer (score 0):

Even though Art's answer is accepted, here is another way using pandas.  You wouldn't need to export the data prior to importing with pandas if you use something like this.

```
import pandas as pd


myFile="lines_to_read2.txt"
myData = pd.DataFrame (columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4'])
mycolumns = 4
thisItem = list()

with open(myFile, 'r') as linesToRead:
    for thisLine in linesToRead:
        thisItem.append(thisLine.strip('\n, " "'))
        if len(thisItem) == mycolumns:
            myData = myData.append({'col1':thisItem[0],'col2':thisItem[1],'col3':thisItem[2],'col4':thisItem[3]}, ignore_index=True)
            thisItem = list()

myData.to_csv('lines_as_csv_file.csv', index=False)
print(myData)   # Full Table
```